# Accessing a file in a runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a program that needs to use a .txt file in it. I have used the following code successfully to run the program right from eclipse:

```
File configFile = new File("src/config.txt");
```

With the file obviuosly residing in the src folder. When I export to a JAR file though it can't find it. I know that you have to get the file as a resource, and I've done this before with images, but I can't get it to work with a file. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
URL fileURL = this.getClass().getResource("config.txt");
File configFile = new File(fileURL);
```

But it won't compile, as it doesn't like the `newFile(fileURL)' portion. I've checked this out online, and found a bunch of stuff, but it all seems to relate to reading the file, and not simply adding it to the JAR. Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you add a file to a jar, if you don't want to read it?

Comment: asked and answered many times -- there are no "files" inside of a jar file. Use it as a resource.

Comment: [Some similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=trying+to+use+a+text+file+in+a+jar+file+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: I need to use the file for the FileReader class, so it needs to be a file.

Comment: I know `InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("configFile.txt");` will work, but again, it won't be a `File`, which I need it to be to work.